# Updating a row using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Note: I am not using Flask-SQLAlchemy here, I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM**

I've seen several answers on StackOverflow saying that this is a way to update a record:

```
session.query(FoobarModel).get(foobar_id).update({'name': 'New Foobar Name!'})
```

However I get an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'FoobarModel' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I was able to update like this, however:

```
foobar = session.query(FoobarModel).get(foobar_id)
foobar.name = 'New Foobar Name!'
session.commit()
session.flush()
```

So then I tried something like this (so that I don't have to write out every property):

```
new_foobar = {'name': 'New Foobar Name!'}
old_foobar = session.query(FoobarModel).get(foobar_id)

for property in new_foobar:
  old_foobar[property] = new_foobar[property]

session.commit()
session.flush()
```

However I then get this error:

```
TypeError: 'FoobarModel' object does not support item assignment
```

After doing some digging I found out that it's because even this wouldn't work:

```
print(old_foobar['name'])
```

Which throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'FoobarModel' object is not subscriptable
```

Honestly the first syntax would be the best in my opinion, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this for your update query:

```
session.query(FoobarModel).filter(FoobarModel.id == foobar_id).update({'name': 'New Foobar Name!'})
```

Since `update()` belongs to [Query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update), and `filter()` does return a `Query` object, this will work, contrary to trying to call `update()` on your `FoobarModel` object (which does not have such a function) returned by `Query.get()`, [see also here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get).

As for looping over your properties and assigning them by name, you could do this with `setattr` and a dict, like this:

```
foobar = session.query(FoobarModel).get(foobar_id)

props = {'name': 'my new name'}

for key, value in props.items():
    setattr(foobar, key, value)

session.commit()
session.flush()
```

This is obviously a little pointless with just one property, but maybe it will come in handy at some point.

Comment: +1 for all the great edits to your answer. This was the problem. I was using `.get()` when I should have been using `.filter()`. Thanks!

Comment: session.flush() should come first, then session.commit(). Since a commit() always flushes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function for SQLAlchemy2.0 based on bgse's solution.

```
from typing import Type
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models

_ENGINE = create_engine(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])

def update(id: int, t: Type[models.Base], props: dict) -> None:
    """Generic function to update an entry in database by ID

    Args:
        id (int): ID of object to update
        t (Type[models.Base]): Type of object to update
        props (dict): Dictionary containing properties to update
    """
    with Session(_ENGINE) as session:
        with session.begin():
            obj = session.get(t, id)
            for field, value in props.items():
                setattr(obj, field, value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Worked

```
device = models.Device.query.filter(models.Device.device_identifier == device_identifier).first()

setattr(device, 'updated_at', datetime.now())
setattr(device, 'ip_address', ip_address)
db.session.commit()
```

Didn't work

```
device.is_active = True
device.id_address = ip_address
device.updated_at = datetime.now()
print(device.ip_address)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: What does “didn’t work” mean? An error? An expectation not fulfilled?